# SVG image Has huge gap top and bottom on responsive site in iPad

Tags: html, ios5, svg, responsive-design, image

I want to use an SVG logo on a site I'm developing if the browser supports it. So I have `<img src="logo.gif" />` in my HTML and then if the browser supports SVG I swap the `src` attribute for `logo.svg`.

This looks great on all devices I've tried it on except a 1st generation iPad that hasn't had its software updated in a few years (it's on iOS 5.1.1). Basically there is a massive gap top and bottom of the logo and I can't work out why. It looks fine on my iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.2 so I'm thinking it's an iOS 5 and below issue.

### My logo.svg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="83.323 19.623 445 109" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#339846" points="121.805,77.839 124.066,86.185 125.199,94.741 125.481,103.087 125.128,110.724 124.42,117.372 
    123.572,122.604 122.936,126.068 122.654,127.271 126.826,121.333 127.815,125.364 129.229,117.159 129.867,109.379 
    129.937,102.097 129.512,95.308 128.806,89.297 127.887,83.992 126.826,79.608 125.905,76.215 125.836,76.285 125.623,76.496 
    125.34,76.709 124.846,76.992 124.278,77.345 123.572,77.558 122.724,77.77 121.805,77.839 "/>
<path fill="#FDCC09" d="M106.488,22.559l-0.14-0.496l1.344,0.354l1.201,0.426l1.201,0.564l1.061,0.637l0.991,0.707l0.919,0.708
    l0.85,0.707l0.777,0.707l0.141,2.052l-0.071,1.132l-0.142,0.989l-0.354,1.557l-0.069-0.071l-0.214-0.213l-0.423-0.283l-0.566-0.495
    l-0.777-0.637l-1.062-0.777l-1.272-0.92l-1.626-1.061l-0.708-2.333l-0.636-1.908L106.488,22.559z M89.121,39.501l0.638,2.191
    l0.424,0.284l0.425,0.284l0.425,0.211l0.425,0.283l0.495,0.283l0.424,0.212l0.424,0.213l0.425,0.212l-0.071-1.981l0.071-1.979
    l0.141-1.91l0.283-1.908l-0.849-0.92l-0.848-0.849l-0.778-0.778l-0.637-0.707l-0.565-0.565l-0.495-0.495l-0.283-0.283l-0.072-0.07
    l-0.563,2.97l0.069,2.758L89.121,39.501z M122.472,66.818l-0.496-2.687l-0.707-2.759l-1.131-2.546l-1.556-2.262l-0.213-0.283
    l-0.707-0.778l-0.92-1.273l-1.061-1.556l-1.062-1.837l-0.989-1.98l-0.707-2.052l-0.353-2.052l0.14-2.191l0.425-2.192l0.495-2.334
    l0.566-2.475l-1.203-0.99l-1.272-0.849l-1.272-0.849l-1.272-0.777l-1.273-0.708l-1.272-0.636l-1.272-0.566l-1.204-0.495l-1.06-0.425
    l-1.062-0.423l-0.849-0.354l-0.777-0.213l-0.708-0.211l-0.424-0.142l-0.354-0.142h-0.069l-0.777,1.697l-0.637,2.121l-0.637,2.475
    l-0.496,2.617l-0.353,2.546l-0.283,2.334l-0.142,1.98v1.344l1.273,0.565l1.273,0.495l1.201,0.495l1.202,0.424l1.202,0.496
    l1.131,0.495l1.062,0.637l0.99,0.637l1.556,1.414l1.273,1.697l1.201,1.909l0.92,1.838l0.707,1.769l0.566,1.484l0.283,0.99
    l0.141,0.353l0.707,1.981l0.989,1.98l1.274,1.839l1.413,1.838l1.557,1.696l1.697,1.557l1.696,1.414l1.768,1.273l0.072-0.99
    l0.07-1.697l-0.07-2.192L122.472,66.818z M136.039,50.604l-1.062-4.386l-1.696-4.242l-2.193-3.96l-2.545-3.749l-2.688-3.394
    l-2.757-3.04l-2.617-2.617l-2.263-2.122l-1.838-1.556l-1.273-0.989l-0.425-0.354l1.838,3.96l0.921,3.536l0.212,3.253l-0.212,2.97
    l-0.496,2.758l-0.637,2.546l-0.423,2.475l-0.142,2.334l0.354,2.051l0.777,2.051l0.918,1.98l1.133,1.838l1.062,1.556l0.919,1.272
    l0.708,0.779l0.212,0.282l1.626,2.475l1.132,2.688l0.707,2.899l0.354,2.758l0.141,2.475v2.051l-0.069,1.344l-0.072,0.496
    l4.668-4.385l3.254-4.455l1.908-4.598l0.777-4.526L136.039,50.604z M118.683,74.71l-1.485-1.204l-1.769-1.626l-1.838-1.908
    l-1.769-2.263l-1.556-2.547l-1.062-2.686l-0.069-0.354l-0.354-0.989l-0.496-1.486l-0.776-1.769l-0.921-1.909l-1.131-1.909
    l-1.344-1.768l-1.557-1.415l-0.989-0.636l-1.061-0.566l-1.061-0.496l-1.203-0.424l-1.2-0.425l-1.273-0.495l-1.273-0.495
    l-1.272-0.565l-1.272-0.708l-1.345-0.777l-1.272-0.92l-1.272-1.06l-1.274-1.273l-1.202-1.485l-1.131-1.768l-1.132-1.979v0.565
    l0.142,1.556l0.211,2.475l0.426,3.111l0.636,3.678l0.92,4.03l1.201,4.173l1.557,4.243l2.05,4.103l2.476,3.746l2.97,3.395
    l3.536,2.688l4.102,1.91l4.809,0.918l5.516-0.211l6.223-1.485l-0.352-0.283L118.683,74.71z"/>
<path fill="#339846" d="M181.058,59.69c-5.656,0-10.842,2.452-14.237,6.506h-0.189l5.47-26.307h-13.672l-9.336,46.579
    c-0.564,2.829-1.037,5.658-1.037,8.486c0,8.203,5.47,12.918,16.407,12.918c20.743,0,30.55-17.16,30.55-32.152
    C195.014,67.517,190.676,59.69,181.058,59.69z M167.292,97.595c-3.111,0-5.092-1.79-5.186-5.091
    c-0.095-1.981,0.188-3.584,0.471-5.092l0.849-3.771c1.603-8.016,6.412-13.013,11.314-13.013c4.148,0,6.034,3.489,6.034,8.015
    C180.774,86.657,175.118,97.595,167.292,97.595z M227.354,59.69c-16.406,0-27.533,13.106-27.533,29.136
    c0,11.409,7.826,19.047,19.519,19.047c16.029,0,27.533-12.353,27.533-29.23C246.872,68.177,239.705,59.69,227.354,59.69z
     M221.225,97.501c-4.714,0-7.354-3.584-7.354-8.958c-0.094-7.166,3.865-18.574,11.691-18.574c5.47,0,7.261,4.525,7.261,8.769
    C232.822,86.657,228.674,97.501,221.225,97.501z M290.997,39.89l-3.959,20.839c-1.981-0.755-4.432-1.038-6.317-1.038
    c-17.445,0-29.043,14.71-29.043,30.738c0,11.222,6.506,17.444,14.332,17.444c5.375,0,11.033-2.357,15.087-8.486h0.188l-0.66,7.449
    h12.447c0.188-5.468,1.037-12.068,2.168-17.916l9.334-49.03H290.997z M282.7,84.018c-1.791,8.768-6.601,12.917-10.466,12.917
    c-3.961,0-6.413-3.11-6.413-8.674c0-8.863,5.752-18.292,13.862-18.292c2.263,0,4.337,0.754,5.374,1.603L282.7,84.018z
     M351.155,60.729l-16.502,33.095c-6.128,12.258-11.597,20.65-17.727,26.402c-5.374,5.092-11.786,7.354-14.805,7.825l-3.016-11.598
    c2.168-0.659,5.186-1.791,7.825-3.676c3.112-2.17,5.752-4.904,7.449-8.017c0.472-0.659,0.472-1.226,0.283-2.264l-9.146-41.769
    h14.331l2.83,20.083c0.66,4.714,1.132,8.015,1.51,10.938h0.188c1.037-2.735,2.074-5.752,4.053-10.749l8.393-20.272H351.155
    L351.155,60.729z M380.384,79.68l12.823,27.156h-15.086l-8.108-19.707l-5.092,4.903l-2.829,14.804h-13.484l12.636-66.946h13.482
    l-7.542,40.073h0.188c1.414-1.791,2.829-3.583,4.149-5.28l11.787-13.955h16.688L380.384,79.68z M406.784,60.729h13.578l-8.77,46.107
    h-13.578L406.784,60.729z M423.286,47.339c0,4.809-3.679,7.638-8.015,7.638h-0.095c-3.677,0-6.506-2.546-6.506-6.6
    c0.095-4.622,3.677-7.732,7.826-7.732C420.457,40.644,423.286,43.284,423.286,47.339z M469.677,72.23
    c0,2.075-0.379,5.562-0.753,7.826l-5.093,26.779h-13.578l4.809-25.553c0.283-1.604,0.471-3.489,0.471-5.187
    c0-3.205-1.132-5.469-4.525-5.469c-4.432,0-9.618,5.562-11.504,15.747l-3.866,20.461h-13.578l5.847-31.117
    c1.131-5.845,1.886-10.937,2.452-14.99h12.068l-0.942,7.637h0.188c4.337-6.035,10.09-8.675,16.217-8.675
    C465.434,59.69,469.677,64.312,469.677,72.23z M514.748,39.89l-3.962,20.839c-1.979-0.755-4.431-1.038-6.318-1.038
    c-17.443,0-29.041,14.71-29.041,30.738c0,11.222,6.505,17.444,14.332,17.444c5.374,0,11.032-2.357,15.087-8.486h0.188l-0.659,7.449
    h12.445c0.188-5.468,1.037-12.068,2.169-17.916l9.334-49.03H514.748z M506.449,84.018c-1.792,8.768-6.601,12.917-10.466,12.917
    c-3.962,0-6.413-3.11-6.413-8.674c0-8.863,5.752-18.292,13.86-18.292c2.264,0,4.339,0.754,5.377,1.603L506.449,84.018z"/>
</svg>
```

My site is responsive so I don't mention height or width in my HTML or SVG and then I set `img { max-width:100%; }` in my CSS. Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is this occurring more in landscape or portrait mode?

Comment: Exactly the same in both. If I put a height and width on the SVG it works but then it isn't responsive.

Comment: What happens if you use a rendered .JPG instead of SVG? Do you see the same behavior? (Yes, I know you want the SVG... I'm just trying to rule out aspect-ratio differences as a cause of the issue you're seeing...)

Comment: Those concerns aside, I assume you're using media queries to create the responsive design...? There's nothing against setting absolute values for different platforms in the different media queries. It might not be as automatic and flexible as you like, but it will at least prevent different platforms from misinterpreting your intentions, and if it works the way that img width/height has worked for years, it may even speed render time as it's effort the parser doesn't need to make ... so it could boost page performance as well to specify both dimensions for each supported aspect ratio.

Comment: No a jpg is fine. Also the site is responsive in a fluid way rather than having set breakpoints so I need the logo to be entirely fluid which rules out any fixed sizes.

Comment: Well, not sure where you could go from here. You mention you're replacing the SRC on the img when you find the browser has SVG support... you could also test browser type at that point and set a width/height with javascript, based on the proportionate measure of another element, I suppose, but that seems heavy handed. FWIW, it does appear that there are several issues that appeared in relation to SVG when Mobile Safari was updated for iOS 5, but I haven't found anything that could be called a resolution for you, sorry. Good luck!

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find more people having issues like this. Thanks very much for your help anyway!

Comment: @MrMisterMan did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry @JMPerez I didn't. I had to go for a good old fashioned GIF instead :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on one of the sites I was working on. It has something to do with setting a width on the SVG element but no height so instead of using a reasonable height it will base the height of the SVG on the body of the document. To get around this, you can use the 1% hack for IOS devices.

```
svg{
  height: 1%;
}
```

So far I have tested this on all modern browsers and devices and the results are as expected.